# Azure Service Bus: consume messages from multiple subscriptions vs forwarding messages to a single input queue

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, service-bus

I'm designing an Azure Service Bus topology with multiple topics. Each topic is associated with a single message type: this is possible since we have a limited number of message types, each one with a well defined semantic meaning in the business domain. Each one of this messages has the meaning of an event inside the system.

Given this context, consider a service which needs to consume more than one message type, let's say two message types.
There are 2 possible ways for this service to consume messages:

- create 2 different subscriptions, one for each topic, and consume messages directly from the subscriptions.
- create a single input queue for the service and 2 different subscriptions, one for each topic. Then, auto forward messages from both subscriptions to the input queue and consume messages from there.

I'm evaluating the tradeoffs between these 2 approaches.

The good thing about the first one is that it is the simplest one in terms of topology, number of message entities and operations.

The second one has different advantages, based on my understanding:

- it decouples the message consumer from the message producers, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding#decouple-message-senders-from-receivers)
- it makes the design less coupled, since by doing so the message consumer only knows its input queue
- it scales better in terms of performances, since there is a single connection to Azure Service bus and a single point where the concurrency should be handled and configured (to be verified, I don't have benchmarks on this).

There are disadvantages also:

- it is more complicated in terms of topology and operations
- there could probably be some impacts in terms of billing, because of the message forwarding action (to be verified)
- it introduces latency
- you have less fine grained control since all message types are forwarded to the very same input queue and are treated in the same way.

Can you please share some suggestion on this topic ? Which is, in your opinion, the best design ?

Comment: isnt there a key difference between the approaches? if you subscribe direclty to a topic, all subscribers get a copy of each message. If you subscribe to a queue, the messages are divided amongst the subscribers

Comment: @Ewan I got your point. Even if you use subscriptions you can have a single subscription with multiple instances of a services all consuming messages from there. You can have competing consumers with subscription in that way

Comment: I remember a similar problem with AWS ages ago, and there was a prefered solution. Not sure with azure. I guess i would be worried about pushing messages to a topic which might have no subscriptions, losing the messages. If you push to a queue at least you know its going somewhere